# Nightwatch how can I make element selector visible within a command?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a test in Nightwatch to test pagination for a grid. I am using Page Objects and element selectors to make maintenance of the test suite easier. It seems, however, that I have run into a limitation with using element selectors within commands. The following code executes without error:

```js
    pagination() {
      var lastPageNum;
      var currentPageNum;
      var newPageNum
      return this
      .getText('@pageNum1', function(result) {
        currentPageNum = parseInt(result.value);
        console.log('Current Page Number = ' + currentPageNum);
      })
      .getText('@pageNum2', function(result) {
        lastPageNum = parseInt(result.value);
        console.log('last Page Number = ' + lastPageNum);
        if (lastPageNum >= 2) {
          this.useXpath()
            .waitForElementVisible('//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/button[3]', 3000)            
            .click('//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/button[3]')
            .getText('//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/span[1]', function(result) {
              newPageNum = parseInt(result.value);
              console.log('New Page = ' + newPageNum);
              this.assert.equal(newPageNum, currentPageNum + 1, "Assert pagination to Next page passed.");
            })
        } else {
          console.log('Not enough rows exist in grid to test pagination, pages = ' + lastPageNum)
        }
      })
    },
```

Note that I am using element selectors for the .getText commands. Here are the selectors I am using:

```js
      pageNum1: {
        selector: '//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/span[1]',
        locateStrategy: 'xpath'
      },

      pageNum2: {
        selector: '//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/span[2]',
        locateStrategy: 'xpath'
      },
```

So far, so good. The issue I am running into is when I attempt to replace the xpath elements inside the .getText command with element selectors as well. Here is the code I am attempting to replace the above with:

```js
pagination() {
      var lastPageNum;
      var currentPageNum;
      var newPageNum
      return this
      .getText('@pageNum1', function(result) {
        currentPageNum = parseInt(result.value);
        console.log('Current Page Number = ' + currentPageNum);
      })
      .getText('@pageNum2', function(result) {
        lastPageNum = parseInt(result.value);
        console.log('last Page Number = ' + lastPageNum);
        if (lastPageNum >= 2) {
          this.useXpath()
            .waitForElementVisible('@nextPageButton', 3000)            
            .click('@nextPageButton')
            .getText('@pageNum1', function(result) {
              newPageNum = parseInt(result.value);
              console.log('New Page = ' + newPageNum);
              this.assert.equal(newPageNum, currentPageNum + 1, "Assert pagination to Next page passed.");
            })
        } else {
          console.log('Not enough rows exist in grid to test pagination, pages = ' + lastPageNum)
        }
      })
    },
```

And here is the additional element selector I am using:

```js
      nextPageButton: {
        selector: '//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/button[3]',
        locateStrategy: 'xpath'
      },
```

When I try to run the test after replacing the xpaths in the .getText command with element selectors, the test fails with the following error:

```
Timed out while waiting for element <@NextPageButton> to be present for 3000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
```

Is there a way to get the element selector to be visible within the .getText command function?

Answer (score 0):

Since there does not appear to be a way to actually use the selectors within a command, I will post the workaround I have been using recently. It is fairly simple: in the page object, I am declaring a constant that contains the web element I want to use as a selector. This needs to be at the top of the page object before declaring the constants or variables you are using to hold the page object methods. The original snippets I posted above only contain the method, not the entire page object, but the declaration needs to happen well before that. Here is an example from the page object that contains the above method:

```
const nPageButton =  '//*[@id="borderLayout_eRootPanel"]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/button[3]';
const gridComands = {
  //page object methods go here
}
```

Once you have declared the web element as a constant,  you can use that constant when constructing your element selector:

```
  nextPageButton: {
    selector: nPageButton,
    locateStrategy: 'xpath'
  },
```

This will allow for easier maintenance, while sacrificing a bit of the functionality that selectors provide. You can use the constant within the page object when the selector does not work, you will just lose the utility of having the locate strategy defined, so you will need to rely on .useXpath() in the method when using xpaths for your web elements.